# Change datasource using bartender dynamically using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net, bartender

I'm populating fields data from database with bartender but I'm not able to do same while changing database from code,

e.g. There is a template called **TestLBL.btw** and in the template we have configured database field say **TestDB.Name** field now I've another database say **TestDB2** and that have exact same fields as **TestDB** now I just wanted to print label with same field with different database(**TestDB2**) using c# code but that doesn't works :(

below is my sample code :

```
btnEngine = new Engine();


                        btnEngine.Start();
                        lblDoc = btnEngine.Documents.Open(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarTenderTemplate_Path"] + templateName);

                        var msg = new Messages();
                        var resolution = new Resolution(300);

                        string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB2"].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections[0].Name = builder.InitialCatalog;
                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections[0].Server = builder.DataSource;
                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections[0].UserID = builder.UserID;
                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections[0].SetPassword(builder.Password);
                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections.SetDatabaseConnection(lblDoc.DatabaseConnections[0]);

                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections.QueryPrompts["pRec_Key"].Value = Rec_key.ToString();
                        lblDoc.DatabaseConnections.QueryPrompts["pImage_Path"].Value = Image_Path;

                        var fileName = templateName.Split('.')[0] + "_" + Rec_key.ToString() + ".pdf";

                        var fileFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarTenderTemplate_Path"]) + "\\" + templateName.Split('.')[0] + "_" + Rec_key.ToString() + ".pdf";
                        var result = lblDoc.ExportPrintPreviewToFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarTenderTemplate_Path"]), fileName, ImageType.PDF
                                 , ColorDepth.ColorDepth24bit, resolution, Color.White, OverwriteOptions.Overwrite, true, true, out msg);

                        lblDoc.Close(SaveOptions.SaveChanges);
```

It throws an error in below line, without any inner exception,

**var result = lblDoc.ExportPrintPreviewToFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarTenderTemplate_Path"]), fileName, ImageType.PDF
                                 , ColorDepth.ColorDepth24bit, resolution, Color.White, OverwriteOptions.Overwrite, true, true, out msg);**

Any help would be appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

**I could not comment the post so i'll ask my question here:**

> 1. What is the error message in this line?

```
var result =  
lblDoc.ExportPrintPreviewToFile(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarTenderTemplate_Path"]), 
    fileName, 
    ImageType.PDF, 
    ColorDepth.ColorDepth24bit, 
    resolution, 
    Color.White, 
    OverwriteOptions.Overwrite, true, true, out msg);
```

> 2. Did you set up **TestDB2** in your BTW file database?

```
string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB2"].ConnectionString;
```

> 3. Did your **fileName** valid?

```
var fileName = templateName.Split('.')[0] + "_" + Rec_key.ToString() + ".pdf";
```